# Blackberry devices requires users to tap drop down fields 3-4 times before the list gets displayed. How do we avoid this delayed response time?

Tags: html, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

We're implementing a hybrid app using IBM Worklight and it seems to be that there is a delayed response time when the user taps on a drop down input field.  This behavior is happening on all blackberry devices.  Is there a solution for this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Could you tell what version of WL are you running, and what Blackberry OS are you trying to support, please?

Comment: It would also help to have code snippets to work with.

Comment: Are you using any JS framework (Dojo, jQuery)? Or this is plain HTML? I.e. what widget are you using to display the drop down control?

Comment: I'm using JS framework 1.3.2 and the input select tag.  WL 6.0.

Comment: This is the JS framework (jQuery framework 1.3.2).  Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

See my reply to the following question. It appears to be pretty much talking about the same issue: [Worklight: Touch sensitivity issue in Blackberry Z10, Q10 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637606/worklight-touch-sensitivity-issue-in-blackberry-z10-q10-devices)

The links within as well mention delayed response when using input fields in a BlackBerry WebWorks-based application, which is the type of BlackBerry app once creates in Worklight