# Worklight: Touch sensitivity issue in Blackberry Z10, Q10 devices

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10

I have developed a Hybrid application for BB10 using IBM Worklight. I am using JQueryMobile. I have a page which has a footer containing links such as Home, About and Contact Us.

The issue is that, the links require multiple taps to hover. Sometimes, the links works in a single tap.

Sample Code

```
<div id="testFooter" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div class="ui-grid">
      <a class="ui-block-a" href="#Home" style="padding:10px;display:block">Home</a>
      <a class="ui-block-b" href="#About" style="padding:10px;display:block">About</a>
      <a class="ui-block-c" href="#Contactus" style="padding:10px;display:block">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to increase the touch area for the anchor as follows. But, this does not solve the problem.

```
<a style="padding:10px;display:block">About</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the time I remember working on BlackBerry, there has always been this delay. Meaning, you must first 'touch' the screen, and only then further taps are recognized.

- Here is a BB dev forum topic that talks about this as well: http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-and-WebWorks-Development/Webworks-App-doesn-t-respond-to-key-events-until-screen-touch/td-p/1714221

I think this is called Navigation Mode or something alike.

- https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/search/?search=navigation+mode&searchaction=Search